# How to delete a relationship of a neo4j node in spring data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have User nodes and having contact relationships with each other. user1 has two contacts user2 and user3. Now I want to delete user2 from contacts. Following is a code snippet about contact relationships.

```
@Node
public class User{
...Id and different properties
@Relationship(type = "CONTACT")
public Set<User> contacts = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Now when I delete a relationship and save back the node it shows the following message:

> WARN 38461 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.d.n.c.m.DefaultNeo4jIsNewStrategy    : Instances of class com.talkkia.api.entity.User with an assigned id will always be treated as new without version property!

Code for deleting relationship is here:

```
@Transactional
@Override
 public String deleteContact(String mobile1, String mobile2) {
        Optional<User> user1 = userRepository.findOneByMobile(mobile1);
        Optional<User> user2 = userRepository.findOneByMobile(mobile2);
        if(user1.get().getContacts().contains(user2.get())){
            user1.get().getContacts().remove(user2.get());
            System.out.println(user1.get().getContacts());
            userRepository.save(user1.get());
            return user2.get().getName() + " has been deleted from your contact.";
        }
        
        return user2.get().getName() + " can't be deleted from contact.";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning message is exactly what leads into the situation you are faced with.
Because you are using an assigned, manual provided id, Spring Data Neo4j cannot differentiate if the object is new or not.
The solution is to provide a `@Version` field in the entity (like `@Version Long version`).
From this SDN can derive the information if the element comes from the database or was newly created.

As a consequence of the wrongly assumed new state of the entity, no relationships will be deleted because it is not necessary from the persistence logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("MATCH(user1:User {mobile: $mobile1})-[c:CONTACT]-(user2:User {mobile:$mobile2}) DETACH DELETE c")
public String deleteContact(String mobile1, String mobile2);
```

Have found the above solution very easy and good in performance I think. @meistermeier point is also valid and considerable.